# NumbersのようにMacの「Finder」やiOSの「ファイル」のようなファイラーを導入する方法

Tags: swift, swift5, swiftui

私が今開発中のアプリはNumbersのようなファイラーが理想的です。

Numbersでは、ファイル選択画面が以下の画像のような見た目になっています。
また、自動保存の保存先は設定アプリのNumbersの項目から変更が可能です。
なのでiCloud以外にもOneDriveなどのオンラインストレージに保存することができます。

もしこの画面も含めて簡単に実装できるのであれば、それに越したことはありません。
ライブラリ等、簡単に実装できる方法がございましたら、教えて頂きたいです。

[image: Numbersの選択画面]

Comment: 質問の対象は「ファイルシステム」ではなく「ファイラー」の間違いではないでしょうか？

Comment: 仰る通りですので、内容を変更しました

Answer (score 1):

こういうUIはOSが用意しているものです。（Windowsで言うところのCommonDialog。）なので呼出し手順を守ればだれでも使えるはずです。ただし、呼べるのはOSが標準で持っているものであって、必ずしもNumbersが使っているものと同じものとは限りません。そこは試してみると良いと思います。

以下のような記事が参考になるのでは。
https://qiita.com/hanamiju/items/d10524e8650ae171fa2e
https://qiita.com/takecian/items/d31682899768f89a8d80

Comment: ちょっと試してみます。SwiftUIで同様の関数が用意されていれば良いのですが……

Comment: iOSであれば UIDocumentPickerViewController とかでしょうか